# Django REST - How do I correctly configure URLs lookup_field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I've made a few django projects and am now experimenting with the rest framework. I'm trying to configure my urls such that url `/testuser/` will take you to the profile page of user with username 'testuser'. Pretty simple task that I can manage in regular django using `slug_field` but I guess I'm not quite understanding how to correctly configure REST urls. Any help appreciated. Code below.

FYI, as you will see below, I am using a `CustomUser` model, linked to a `Profile` model by `OneToOneField`. The username is stored in the `CustomUser` model. However, the profile page will be populated using `ProfileSerializer`.

I believe the issue might be the way I am accessing the 'username' from the related model, CustomUser - but I could be wrong (likely, lol). Anyone have any idea?

**My current code throws the error:**

```
Expected view ProfileView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "username". Fix your URL conf, or set the .lookup_field attribute on the view correctly.
```

**users.models**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='username',
        max_length=40,
        unique=True,
    )
    ...
```

**profiles.models**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile'
    )
    ...
```

**profiles.serializers**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="user.username")

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username', 'display_name', 'profile_pic',
                  'bio', 'following', 'modified', 'est', )
        model = Profile
        lookup_field = 'username'
```

**profiles.views**

```
class ProfileView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
```

**profiles.urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='self_profile'),
]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is expecting `username` URL parameter, but it receives `slug`. You can either change your URL to pass on `username` instead of slug, or set `lookup_url_kwarg` to `slug` on your view to fix that situation.

Comment: This seems so straightforward now... Thank you. I have always used 'slug' field in urls so I guess I thought it was standard and the 'lookup_field' converted that value to a slug. Silly - but all working now. Thanks